# How can I print some text in a textbox on excel userform

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, textbox

So basically what I am doing, is that I have 2 dependant ComboBoxes on a userform, and a third value will be printed on a textbox.
For example, I choose value animal in ComboBox 1, Then I have some values on ComboBox 2 depending on my first choice, in this exemple I have (cat, dog,birds) I choose Dog in my ComboBox 2, and then I have a unique text that should be automatically printed on my textbox. like : "You're a dog lover". If I ever choose another value such as cat I should have a unique text ("You're a cat lover") etc.
Now watching several tutorials, I have this :

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()

    Dim sh As Worksheet

    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DListes")

        Dim i As Integer
    
    Me.ComboBox3.Clear
    
    
    If Me.ComboBox1 = "[SUB_SYSTEM_PMN] LONAV" Then
        If Me.ComboBox2 = "DCEE" Or Me.ComboBox2 = "EEAD" Then
              Me.ComboBox3.AddItem sh.Range("C2") '***Here is the Point**'
        ElseIf Me.ComboBox2 = "NT" Or Me.ComboBox2 = "LI" Then
              Me.ComboBox3.AddItem sh.Range("I4") '***Here too**'
        End If
    If Me.ComboBox1 = "DIS" Then
        If Me.ComboBox2 = "DCEE" Or Me.ComboBox2 = "EEAD" Then
              Me.ComboBox3.AddItem sh.Range("H2") '***Here too**'
        ElseIf Me.ComboBox2 = "NT" Or Me.ComboBox2 = "LI" Then
              Me.ComboBox3.AddItem sh.Range("I4") '***Here too**'
End If
    
    End Sub
```

Now as you can see, I used

```
Me.ComboBox3.AddItem sh.Range("C2")
```

and

```
Me.ComboBox3.AddItem sh.Range("I4")
```

Because for the moment I only retrieve the text in a Combobox, but I want to retrieve it in a textbox, because now I have to click on the third ComboBox, and then choose only one value, and since there is only one, I have to make it printed directly.
What should I replace this:

```
Me.ComboBox2.Value = sh.Range("H" & i)
```

with.

Thnks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you want a Combobox to display a text automatically, just set the property `ListIndex` to the index of the item (counting starts at 0). So to display the 1st entry, you would use something like this:

```
With Me.ComboBox3
    .Clear
    .AddItem "Hallo"
    .ListIndex = 0
End With
```

If you just want to display the text and don't need a Combobox (the user shouldn't select anything), you can use a Textbox. You set the text of an Textbox using the `Value`-property:

```
Me.TextBox1.Value = "Hello"
```

However, a Textbox is an input field. If you want to prevent that the user enters something, you need to set the `enabled`-property to `False`. That has the drawback that the text is displayed with a gray font which makes it hard to read.

An alternative is to use a simple Label. For a label, you set the text via the `Caption`-property:

```
Me.Label1.Caption = "Hello"
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your response.
I actually tried
`Me.TextBox1.Value = sh.Range("I4")`
But it didn't work. like is there a problem with my code.

Comment: Is Range I4 filled with the expected value (check with the debugger)? Either it's empty or contains an error or your code is not triggered at all.

Comment: Complementing the excellent comment of @FunThomas the TextBox has the 'Locked' property (set it as 'True'), that has the advantage of display the text as is, and blocking editions by the user.

Comment: Thanks to you both, i'll try it and get back to you guys

Comment: Hiii, it worked.
I Tried
`Me.TextBox1.Value = "Hello"`
and it worked.
I also tried
`Me.TextBox1.Value = sh.Range("I4")`
And it worked too, idk why it didn't last time, but nevermind, thanks.